# Clarke's generalized gradient formula computed on functions defined on open sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, control-theory, non-smooth-analysis

In the book [1], Clarke et al. define the generalized gradient for a Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ as follows.

> 8.1. Theorem (Generalized Gradient Formula). Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be Lipschitz near $x$. Let $\Omega$ be any subset of zero measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\Omega_f$ be the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ at which $f$ fails to be differentiable. Then,
>   \begin{equation*}
>  \partial f(x):=co\{\lim\nabla f(x_i):x_i\to x, x_i\notin\Omega,x_i\notin\Omega_f\}
> \end{equation*}

In other words, the generalized gradient of $f$ at $x$ is the convex hull whose elements are the limiting points of the gradient of $f$ computed at the elements of sequences converging to $x$. Moreover, these elements of sequences do not belong to any set of measure zero nor to the set of points where $f$ fails to be differentiable.

Here follows my question. If $f$ is defined on any open subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$, does the above formula hold as below

Let $x\in S$, and $\Omega(S)$ be any subset of $S$ with measure zero with respect to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\Omega_f(S)$ be the set of points in $S$ at which $f$ fails to be differentiable. Then,
\begin{equation*}
 \partial f(x):=co\{\lim\nabla f(x_i):x_i\to x, x_i\notin\Omega(S),x_i\notin\Omega_f(S)\} ?
\end{equation*}

My answer is no, because $S$ is open. Consequently, $S$ does not contains the limit $\lim\nabla f(x_i)$. Thus, $\partial f(x)$ may not be defined in $S$. Is this reasoning correct?

References

[1] Clarke et al, "Nonsmooth Analysis and Control Theory", Springer 1998

Comment: I am not sure what exactly are you saying but consider the following example: Let $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ with $f(x)=|x|$. The generalized gradient of $f$ is well defined in $(-1,1)$ and is given by $\partial f(x)=sign(x)$ for every $x\in(-1,1)$ except zero and $\partial f(0)=[-1,1]$.

Comment: What is the reason for the arbitrary measure zero set $\Omega$. It serves no purpose that I can discern.

Comment: According to the comment made in [1] by Clarke et al., "points $x'$ belonging to any prescribed set of measure zero can be ignored in the construction without changing the result"

Comment: That isn't as trivial as it first sounds. It is conceivable that $\Omega$ contains sequences converging to $x$ such that the limit of the gradient falls outside the convex hull of the limits for sequences outside of $\Omega$. I can only presume that they've shown somewhere that this can't actually occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $S$ does not contain $\lim \nabla f(x_i)$, but I fail to see any significance to this fact as I can see no point in demanding that the range of a gradient must be contained within its domain. Would you demand that $f\ :\ (0, \infty) \to \Bbb R\ :\ x \mapsto \frac 1x$ has no derivative because $f'(x) < 0$?

Your definition only works for $x \in \overline{(S - \Omega_f(S) - \Omega(S))}$ (unless you are happy with the empty set as a value), but this is only to be expected.

Comment: Thank you, Paul Sinclair. In fact, I forgot to add some context. Consider the case in which $f$ is a candidate-Lyapunov function. In such a case, the range of a gradient is required to be contained within its domain.